# Advanced find and replace?

Tags: microsoft-word, html

i'm trying to a get really huge amount of links into one single list and filter out unwanted sites. i've already tried to use the find a replace in word and chrome but it won't get past .com because everything after that varies but i need all of these variations. pretty much the issue is whenever i want to  select these links i can't get to all of the different variations (they are all different youtube links) and i can only select the fields that are the same. is there any way of getting every link selected even though they are different?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are on windows from the fact you suggested word. You haven't been too clear about exactly what you want to find and exactly what you want to replace so I am assuming you have each website on a new line (or separated by a particular character. If they match a certain string you should delete them

Save as a .txt file and ([install](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) then) open notepad++

Open the find and replace option in notepad++

If you want to remove any youtube sites you should be able to use the search string

```
http://*youtube.com/*\n
```

Where the *s are for wildcards (anything) and the \n is for the new line at the end. The wildcard between http:// and youtube is to allow for the www. to be there or not. I don't have a windows computer handy to check this works perfectly but it should be a good start.